# List of commits relative to pushes (remote)

Tags: git

I'd like to get a list of pushes relative to some remote branch, and if that's possible, I'd like to be able to list the commits relative to any specific push operation.

I've tried searching all over but to no avail so far.

Answer (score 0):

The ["push"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) is just a synching between two git repositories. In a typical case its the synching between the copy of the git repo on your local machine to a central repo. AFAIK the push is not really recorded as an artifact in the git meta data. So you cannot refer a push by any identifier.

So to get to your question, you will be able to find differences between two different commits, or two different states of the same branch assuming it has not been pushed/synced.

Here are a few commands that will help you do that:
`git log --oneline --name-only develop..origin/develop`

This will give you a list of all commits between the local `develop` branch and the `remote develop` branch, this will also give you list of all the files changed in that commit. If you dont want file names just remove the `--name-only` arg.

And if you want to visualize, you can use `git log --oneline --name-only --graph develop..origin/develop`.

THe ```` develop..origin/develop``` can be tags, commits or branches. In git speak ```tree-ish ````.

You can potentially tag pushes and then figure out the diff between tags.